# Modulo in conditional ternary operator

Tags: c++

In C++, someone wrote the following:

```
player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;
```

From what I've read, the variable 'player' will evaluate to 1 if the condition inside the parantheses is true, but this doesn't seem like a condition which can either be true or false.

Comment: Implicit conversions. This is terrible code, but unfortunately quite common. The conditional *should* be written as `player % 2 == 1`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `player` is an `int` or has in implicit conversion to `int`, then the modulo operation will either return `0` or `1` in this case for even or odd respectively.

From there, `int` has an implicit conversion to `bool` such that `0` evaluates to `false` and all non-zero values (including negative values) evaluate to `true`.

**Example**
Starting with

```
player = 2;
```

We can follow the ternary expression step-by-step

```
player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;
player = (2 % 2) ? 1 : 2;
player = 0 ? 1 : 2;  // 0 evaluates to false
player = 2;
```

However, I think this logic is flawed, they probably meant

```
player = (player % 2) ? 2 : 1;
```

This will indeed "switch" the players in an alternating fashion, meaning when `player` is initially `1`, after the ternary it will be assigned `2` and vice versa.